# Capture error using OUT parameter in Oracle's procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have to create procedure to insert row into table, also I need to include am OUT parameter that would capture any errors. However when I test using anonymous block it would not work, but if I use exception in procedure it is working. It means if I add an OUT parameter and I pass values from the block it won't work.

This code works but is not what I want:

```
    create or replace 
    PROCEDURE EXAM_SP 
(P_FIRSTNAME IN BB_SHOPPER.FIRSTNAME%TYPE,
 P_LASTNAME  IN BB_SHOPPER.LASTNAME%TYPE,
 P_ADDRESS IN BB_SHOPPER.ADDRESS%TYPE,
 P_CITY IN BB_SHOPPER.CITY%TYPE,
 P_STATE IN BB_SHOPPER.STATE%TYPE,
 P_ZIP IN BB_SHOPPER.ZIPCODE%TYPE)


IS  

BEGIN
INSERT INTO BB_SHOPPER (IDSHOPPER, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY,   
STATE, ZIPCODE)
VALUES                   
(BB_SHOPPER_IDSHOPPER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,P_FIRSTNAME,P_LASTNAME,P_ADDRESS, 
                        P_CITY, P_STATE,P_ZIP);

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Code = '||SQLCODE); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Message = Please check input');     
END EXAM_SP;.
```

But in code above if I name out parameter it won't work, not sure how to do this, if I add OUT parameter to procedure and pass values:

```
    create or replace 
    PROCEDURE EXAM_SP 
(P_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
 P_LASTNAME  IN VARCHAR2,
 P_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
 P_CITY IN VARCHAR2,
 P_STATE IN CHAR,
 P_ZIP IN VARCHAR2,
 P_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2)......
```

I will receive this error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

If I remove parameter and use original code on the beginning it works.

Anonymous block that gets that error:

```
DECLARE
  LV_FIRSTNAME_TXT BB_SHOPPER.FIRSTNAME%TYPE := 'FIRST';
  LV_LASTNAME_TXT BB_SHOPPER.LASTNAME%TYPE := 'LAST';
  LV_ADDRESS_TXT BB_SHOPPER.ADDRESS%TYPE := '8899 TAPE PARK';
  LV_CITY_TXT BB_SHOPPER.CITY%TYPE := 'JACKSONVILLE';
  LV_STATE_TXT BB_SHOPPER.STATE%TYPE := 'FLd';
  LV_ZIP_NUMBER BB_SHOPPER.ZIPCODE%TYPE := '34567';
  LV_ERROR varchar2(100);

BEGIN 
  EXAM_SP(LV_FIRSTNAME_TXT, LV_LASTNAME_TXT, LV_ADDRESS_TXT,      
    LV_CITY_TXT,LV_STATE_TXT,LV_ZIP_NUMBER);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_ERROR);
END;
```

Procedure:

```
  create or replace 
  PROCEDURE EXAM_SP 
(P_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
 P_LASTNAME  IN VARCHAR2,
 P_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
 P_CITY IN VARCHAR2,
 P_STATE IN CHAR,
 P_ZIP IN VARCHAR2,
 P_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2)



IS  

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO BB_SHOPPER (IDSHOPPER, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS, CITY, 
                        STATE, ZIPCODE)
  VALUES                  
         (BB_SHOPPER_IDSHOPPER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,P_FIRSTNAME,P_LASTNAME,P_ADDRESS, 
                        P_CITY, P_STATE,P_ZIP);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  P_ERROR := SQLCODE;

/*DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Code = '||SQLCODE); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Message = Please check input'); 
P_ERROR := SQLCODE;*/

END EXAM_SP;
```

Error message that I am receiving:

```
Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 6
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

I have passed variable `'FLd'` to procedure parameter in order to test error capture.

Table structure:

```
IDSHOPPER   NUMBER(4,0)
FIRSTNAME   VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
LASTNAME    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
ADDRESS VARCHAR2(40 BYTE)
CITY    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
STATE   CHAR(2 BYTE)
ZIPCODE VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
PHONE   VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
FAX VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
EMAIL   VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
USERNAME    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
PASSWORD    VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)
COOKIE  NUMBER(4,0)
DTENTERED   DATE
PROVINCE    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
...
```

Comment: Why do you want to use an out parameter instead of just letting the caller see the exception directly (and also see the error stack)? Anyway, it isn't clear what problem you are having; why not show us the code that *doesn't* work and the errors or problems you have with that code?

Comment: I wanted to pass back, in this instance to anonymous block and print out, or show to user as prompt. If I add out parameter to procedure and I pass values I will receive this error:                                                             create or replace 
PROCEDURE EXAM_SP 
    (P_FIRSTNAME IN VARCHAR2,
     P_LASTNAME  IN VARCHAR2,
     P_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
     P_CITY IN VARCHAR2,
     P_STATE IN CHAR,
     P_ZIP IN VARCHAR2,
     P_ERROR OUT VARCHAR2).......

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45523242/edit) to show your complete new procedure *and* the anonymous block you are using; and the error stack trace so we can see exactly where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have edited my question, thank you guys for your time.

Comment: BB_SHOPPER.STATE is char.

Comment: Never use `CHAR` for anything.

Comment: Also, avoid using `SQLCODE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error stack shows:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 6
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
```

That stack shows, partly because it doesn't mention the procedure name, that the error is from line 6 of the anonymous block. It isn't getting as far as the call to the procedure on line 11 of that block.

The problem is that you've defined the local state variable:

```
LV_STATE_TXT BB_SHOPPER.STATE%TYPE := 'FLd';
```

using the `%TYPE` syntax, which is great; but as the table column is `char(2)`, when you try to assign the three-character text literal `'Fld'` to that two-character local variable it immediately errors at that point.

it is *not* getting as far as sending the three-character value to the procedure, so the error you're expecting from the `insert` doesn't appear because the `insert` doesn't happen either.

If you want to break it with that particular error you can either change the local variable declaration to be a fixed length instead of using `%TYPE` as you would normally want to:

```
DECLARE
  LV_FIRSTNAME_TXT BB_SHOPPER.FIRSTNAME%TYPE := 'FIRST';
  LV_LASTNAME_TXT BB_SHOPPER.LASTNAME%TYPE := 'LAST';
  LV_ADDRESS_TXT BB_SHOPPER.ADDRESS%TYPE := '8899 TAPE PARK';
  LV_CITY_TXT BB_SHOPPER.CITY%TYPE := 'JACKSONVILLE';
  --LV_STATE_TXT BB_SHOPPER.STATE%TYPE := 'FLd';
  -- specific length to allow invalid value to be used
  LV_STATE_TXT char(3) := 'FLd';
  LV_ZIP_NUMBER BB_SHOPPER.ZIPCODE%TYPE := '34567';
  LV_ERROR varchar2(100);

BEGIN 
  EXAM_SP(LV_FIRSTNAME_TXT, LV_LASTNAME_TXT, LV_ADDRESS_TXT,      
    LV_CITY_TXT,LV_STATE_TXT,LV_ZIP_NUMBER,LV_ERROR);

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_ERROR);
END;
/

-12899

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or more simply use literals directly for the IN parameters, as you are just testing the procedure at this point:

```
DECLARE
  LV_ERROR varchar2(100);
BEGIN 
  EXAM_SP('FIRST', 'LAST', '8899 TAPE PARK',      
    'JACKSONVILLE', 'FLd', '34567', LV_ERROR);

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_ERROR);
END;
/

-12899

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You might find it more useful to return the error text, not just the number (and if you're returning the error number use a numeric formal argument type!), e.g:

```
...
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_ERROR := SQLERRM;
END EXAM_SP;
/

-- same anonymous block

ORA-12899: value too large for column "MY_SCHEMA"."BB_SHOPPER"."STATE" (actual: 3, maximum: 2)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

Of course, as I mentioned in a comment, it's better to let Oracle's exception handling just bubble the actual exception up to the caller - aside maybe from logging, you should only really catch exceptions you can actually handle. Notice that the error message that's passed back doesn't tell you anything about *where* the error occurred in the code; without the exception handler you would see the line number in the procedure that had the offending statement. And as APC points out, every caller has to look for and handle the resposne, and it would be easy to overlook. There are always exceptions (ha) of course, but this seems to be an exercise in doing things wrong.

Comment: thank you so much for very detailed answer and assistance, I know it takes time to review go over and do give useful pointers and advises. Thank you again a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

> "If I add out parameter to procedure and I pass values I will receive this error"

Alex has provided the long answer, I'm just going to make one short point: this is bad practice. Most programming languages include built-in functionality for handling exceptions. What you propose creates two architectural problems:

1. Programs which call your procedure have to write non-standard code to catch errors, which is just a pain for both the developers who write the calling programs and everybody else who has to understand how they work.
2. Your procedure doesn't hurl an exception so even though it "failed" it returns a success state to calling programs. If the developer who wrote the calling program didn't implement the special code the exception is lost and the database can be left in an invalid state.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance and time, I am relatively new to writing procedures, functions and/or pkgs. Still quite road ahead to learn and pick tips here and at my workplace when I can. Thank you again :)